# No events where emmited. Why?

Tags: solidity, truffle-test

This is not a duplicate question. The other one doesn't answer the problem in any way. Can anyone explain to me why do I get `No Events where emmited` when running truffle test? Ganache is listening in 7545 and my truffle config file points to that port. 
I can see more blocks being produced in Ganache each time I run truffle test.

I am starting to think it has nothing to do with the contract code or the truffle test, but here they are:

Contract code

```
function addExam(string memory hash) public returns (string memory examProfessorHash) {
    // save the exam hash and link it with the professors address
    professorsExam[msg.sender] = hash;

    return professorsExam[msg.sender];
}
```

Test code

```
it("should add an exam to the exams list", async () => {
    let hash_test = "9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08";
    let instance = await Exam.deployed();
    let hash = await instance.addExam(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]});
    assert.equal(hash.valueOf(), hash_test, "Not returning the correct address");
```

Why do I get

> Contract: Exams
>   ✓ should pass this test
>
> No events were emitted
>
> 1) should add an exam to the exams list
>
> No events were emitted

Comment: Can you at least link to the question that you find insufficient? Thanks

Comment: Side note: you're suffering misconception of how things work. When you call a non-constant (neither `pure` nor `view`) function **from the off-chain** (i.e., from a web3 script and not from another contract), you do not get back the value that this function returns, because it is not known whether the transaction has been mined. Instead, you get a transaction-hash (don't confuse this with the fact that yur return-value happens to be named "hash", probably due to your internal logic).

Comment: In order to obtain the actual return-value, you need to: 1. In the contract - emit an event containing the return-value, before returning it. 2. In the script - obtain the receipt associated with that transaction-hash, and extract the event from it. You may get the receipt directly (i.e., instead of taking the transaction hash and request the corresponding receipt from the node), if you `await` for the transaction to complete (as you do in your case). So all you really have left to do is something like `emit MyEvent(professorsExam[msg.sender])` before `return professorsExam[msg.sender]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `addExam` function is not a `view` or `pure` function and it modifies the state of the contract. Therefore it returns a transaction hash and not the real function return value because the transaction needs to be mined before it can give you the result.

Your test fails because you `assert` that the return value is the desired address when the return value is only the transaction hash. And when a truffle test fails it shows you the events which were emitted during the execution - in your case you are not emitting any events and therefore it just says that no events were emitted. You can read a bit more detauls here: [How to fix "No events were emitted"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60720/how-to-fix-no-events-were-emitted)

Answer (score 0):

Following my comments to your question (please read through), here is how you can fix your code:

**In the contract:**

```
event ExamAdded(string hash);

function addExam(string memory hash) public returns (string memory examProfessorHash) {
    // save the exam hash and link it with the professors address
    professorsExam[msg.sender] = hash;
    emit ExamAdded(professorsExam[msg.sender]);
    return professorsExam[msg.sender];
}
```

**In the test:**

```
it("should add an exam to the exams list", async () => {
    const hash_test = "9F86D081884C7D659A2FEAA0C55AD015A3BF4F1B2B0B822CD15D6C15B0F00A08";
    const instance = await Exam.deployed();
    const response = await instance.addExam(hash_test, {from: accounts[0]});
    assert.equal(response.logs[0].args.hash, hash_test, "Not returning the correct address");
});
```

Note that:

- `emit ExamAdded(professorsExam[msg.sender]);` is useful only when the function is called from the off-chain (i.e., from a web3 script)
- `return professorsExam[msg.sender];` is useful only when the function is called from the on-chain (i.e., from this contract or from another contract)

Therefore, you should generally add each one of these statements only if they are really needed.

Side note: for your purpose, it seems that you can use `bytes32` instead of `string`, which would make your code more efficient (less gas-consuming).

Comment: This is changing the testing logic, not testing for the actual return value. But maybe that's ok for the OP, unsure.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: Well, that's true I suppose, though since the emit statement and the return statement are identical in contents, it kinda keeps the logic I believe.